# mysql insert and update on duplicate

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, on-duplicate-key

I have table with several cols and I'm doing a multiplier insert to it.

ie:

```
INSERT INTO accounting_positions
KEYS (`date`, `customer`, `type`, `product`, `volume`, `payout`, `count`)
VALUES ('2012-01-10','10','regular','60sec',65,83,13),
('2012-01-10','10','regular','binary',15,83,13)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE volume=volume+CURRENT_COL_VAL;
```

what should I write instead of the "CURRENT_COL_VAL"?
if I want to update the duplicate row with a value from my insert.

because I cant place a static number inside it because it is differs with every row insert in the multiple insert

Comment: where do you get from the static numbers above? Is there any of them being the volume?

Comment: I edited the insert query so you could see the table keys, with every insert row you get different data so each insert the update on duplicate key is differing

Comment: so why are you putting a hardcoded "65" value for `volume` here since it changes all the time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have a look at the [mysql docu on insert-on-duplicate](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) From there you can see that you can use something like this:

```
INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3),(4,5,6)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=VALUES(a)+VALUES(b);
```

in your case:

```
INSERT INTO accounting_positions
    (`date`, `customer`, `type`, `product`, `volume`, `payout`, `count`)
VALUES 
    ('2012-01-10','10','regular','60sec',65,83,13),
    ('2012-01-10','10','regular','binary',15,83,13)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE volume=volume+VALUES(volume);
```

which would add the new and the old value. If you only want the given insert value to overwirite the row then do: `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE volume=VALUES(volume)`